# Вывести картинку с определенным окончанием

Tags: javascript

У меня есть клик на картинку ,при котором появляется модалка с этой же картинкой только увеличенной.
Мне надо чтоб при нажатии на картинку ,например /img/derevo.png появлялась модалка с /img/derevo-big.png. То есть при нажатии на картинку,чтоб он искал -big в названии картинки и выводил его в модалку.

```
setBigPicture() { ////////// это сам клик 
        const icons = this.block.find('.big');
        const bigMODAL = this.block.find('.features-big-img');
        const modalPic = this.block.find('.features-big-img img');

        icons.on('click', e => {
            
        const im = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('src');
            modalPic.attr('src',im);
            bigMODAL.show();
        });
        bigMODAL.on('click', e => {
            $('.features-big-img ').hide();
            $(document).unbind('click');
            e.stopPropagation()
        });

    }
}

\\\\\\\\\\\это модалка 
<div class="features-big-img">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <img src="" >
</div>
```

Comment: В чём, собственно, проблема?

Answer (score 0):

А такой вариант не устроит?

```js
function openBigPicture(s) {
  document.getElementById("big-photo").innerHTML = "<img src=" + 
    s.substring(0, s.length - 4) + "-big.jpg" + "></img>" + 
    "<p>Сейчас я запросил фото: " + s.substring(0, s.length - 4) + "-big.jpg" + "</p>" + "<p>А оригинал был: " + s + "</p>"
 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/better-smartphone-photos.jpg" width=200 onclick="openBigPicture('https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/better-smartphone-photos.jpg')">

<span id=big-photo></span>
```